# Python: Decoding NLS encoded text

Tags: python, nls-lang

I'm using a Corba library where the target returns error messages with NLS encoding.  e.g: wideNlsText=u'$NLS[30822b0b\x01888\x01$NLS[30822ae5\x013\x01Subscriber NPA]NLS$]NLS$'

Other than $NLS starts and NLS$ ends the string, what can I do to translate these into a more acessable text string?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies all,

Further reading of the documentation says:

The XXXX Server provides National Language Support (NLS) for all string values returned across the CORBA API.  The client application specifies the locale of these strings by calling the setNLSLocale method.  If the locale is not set the string values are returned as NLS identifiers that are not interpretable by the client application.  Future releases will provide an additional interface for interpreting these NLS identifiers (see  Future releases).  The client application can query the NLS locale by calling getNLSLocale.

Please consider the question closed

Comment: But please also mark this answer as accepted so this question no longer shows up as unresolved. Thanks.